# Whitelist Cloud 9 SSH Workspace in AWS

Tags: ssh, cloud

I would like to use Cloud 9 SSH Workspace to SSH into my AWS EC2 instance. I would like to do this for many reasons, one of which is that I am not allowed to install an SSH client on my work computer. I need to know the IP of the C9 SSH Workspace so I can whitelist it in AWS but this is difficult for some reason.

I have tried using `tcpdump` to find where C9 logs in from, and white listed the IPs, however this does not work. The only way I can SSH into my EC2 instance is if I allow SSH to all IPs (0.0.0.0/0), which I don't want to do for obvious reasons.

Does anyone have any advice on how to whitelist a C9 instance?

Comment: Why not just connect from your "Cloud 9 SSH Workspace" (I have absolutely no idea what it is) when your ssh is  configured to allow from 0.0.0.0/0 then see what IP you are connecting from (should be displayed on login or see `last`) and then reconfigure your ssh daemon with this information (hoping of course your IP would not change after)?

Answer (score 1):

You can use jump ssh. Use a server just for accessing to other servers (let's call it Access_server) and in the configuration of cloud9 setup the jump ssh field with the ip of the Access_server (user@Access_server:22).
In the cloud9 server allow ssh for only the Access_server and then you have it.